# DynamoDB Table Design for User/Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, partitioning

I've been reading up on DynamoDB table design. I'm still not 100% sure on the best approach for this.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html

The use case is a `User` has a variety of settings, and `User` can belong to one `Group`. The `Group` can has default settings. So the plan is load the `User` settings + `Group` settings for that user, combine them together to form the actual settings.

The plan is to store the settings, in several keys, so

- `PK` = customer#1, `SK` = setting1, columns (A,B,C)
- `PK` = customer#1, `SK` = setting2, columns (D,E,F)
- `PK` = customer#1, `SK` = setting3, columns (X,Y,Z)
- `PK` = customer#1, `SK` = ApiKey, `ApiKey` ="qwerty"
- `PK` = customer#1, `SK` = group#A

Then the group would have what it needs, i.e. it has defaults for

- PK = group#A, SK = setting2, columns (D,E,F)

The read pattern would need to be

- lookup by customer (so just `PK`)

  - Query customer#1 returns multiple rows
  - Get group name, then query again by group#A to return multiple rows
- lookup by group (so just `PK`)

  - Query group#A returns multiple rows
- lookup customers by group (so just `SK`)

  - Cannot query, so scan by SK=group#A

The lookup by group has me stumped, I shouldn't be scanning. Does this SK need to be a GSI, with the `SK` being the `PK` of the GSI?

I also have another use case, that the user has an API Key, and would like to lookup based on API Key.

- `PK` = customer#1, `SK` = ApiKey, `ApiKey` = "qwerty"

Even if I added a GSI to the SK, then in this case, I would still need another GSI on `ApiKey` column. It feels waste to add another GSI just for this, so feel that I do not understand the best practice to structure it. In the AWS docs they had several queries working with just 2 GSIs.

Comment: The best practice with DynamoDB like many NoSQL databases is you bind all the associated data together in a single entity. When you fetch the row, you should retrieve all the associated data. You have to design the table in that way.

Comment: @Prabhakaran doing this runs the risk that the row will exceed a maximum size, as you are limited to 400KB, and as the different settings are for different areas, the idea was to split the rows based on logical ownership, rather than have multiple tables.

Comment: Understood. But, your business case is going to exceed 400KB? On the other hand, if you are going to store the apiKey as a separate column, yes, you have to use either secondary index or (query with the PK and filter the result). Avoid scan at all cost

Comment: FYI - I've redesigned the table and just put everything into a single row. I just thought of the back o the AWS docs there was something clear in the GSI approach with the pk/sk that allowed efficient sorting.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the update. Let me know the final approach that you are going to take. Would love to learn from that.